# Pass Doctrine Entity Manager to a Service

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to pass in the Doctrine Entity Manager so I can access my repositories etc. but I'm having some trouble.

My service is defined:

```
mlbp_beer.rest.controller:
    class: MLBP\BeerBundle\Controller\RestController
    arguments: 
      em: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

This gives me an error:

```
ParameterNotFoundException: The service "mlbp_beer.rest.controller" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "doctrine.orm.entity_manager".
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks right? Make sure rest is defined in your routing.yml like so.. Clear the cache too!

```
rest:
    resource: mlbp_beer.rest.controller
    type:     rest
```

Comment: That did it, already had it defined like that but after clearing the cache it just seemed to start working